# How to convert an image to a Box2D polygon using the alpha layer and triangulation?

Tags: image, box2d, polygon, rounding, edge-detection

I'm coding a game using Box2D and SFML, and I'd like to let my users import their own textures to use as physics polygons. The polygons are created using the images' alpha layer. It doesn't need to be pixel perfect, and this is where my problem is. If it's pixel-perfect, it's going to be way too buggy when the player gets stuck between two rather complex shapes. I have a working edge-detection algorithm, and it produces something like [this](http://pastebin.com/r4TNKGC6). It's pixel per pixel (and the shape it's tracing is simply a square with an dip). After that, I have a simplifying algorithm that produces [this](http://pastebin.com/6ftAHg9v). It works fine to me, but if every single corner is traced like that, I'm going to have some problems. The code for the vector-simplifying is this:

```
    //borders is a std::vector containing simple Box2D b2Vec2 (2D vector class containing an x and a y)
    //vector shortener
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < borders.size(); i++)
    {
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        //get the values for x and y that need to be added to check whether in a line or not
        x = borders[i].x - borders[i-1].x;
        y = borders[i].y - borders[i-1].y;
        //while points are aligned..
        while((borders[i].x + x*counter == borders[i + counter].x) && (borders[i].y + y*counter == borders[i+counter].y))
        {
            counter++;
        }
        if(counter-1 > i)
        {
            borders.erase(borders.begin() + i, borders.begin() + i + counter -1);
        }
    }
```

So my question is, how can I transform the previous set of vectors into something a bit less precise? Are there any rounding algorithms out there? If so, which is best? Any tips you can give me? It doesn't matter whether the resulting polygon is convex or concave, I'm triangulating it anyways.

Thanks,
AsterAlff

Comment: You can look at source of [Physics2D.Net](https://code.google.com/p/physics2d/) at file  Physics2DDotNet/Shapes/BitmapHelper.cs. Looks like there realized what you need.

Comment: The code, being uncommented, is really hard to interpret, especially for this type of stuff, and it being C# (and me doing C++). I'm not sure which function does what.. Care to point to the one you were thinking of?

Comment: Looks like CreateFromBitmap. It gets two-dimensional array (IBitmap) and returns list of points. See also, it contains two steps - generating and reducing (like you do). I think, you will find usefull Reduce method.